# Alternative to google map api, so that I can use it on a HTTPS/SSL encrypted website

Tags: api, open-source, google-maps, dictionary

I have a question regarding map api.

I was using the the google map api in my website before. But since I have encryption the site using HTTPS/SSL support, the google map api stopped working. I checked online, and realised that google has a Premier account only that would allow me to use HTTPS supported maps api and it cost $10,000 per year.

I do not this kind of money with me. So, can you give any other alternative to have a map api on my website. Anything that could give me driving directions would be fine.

Regards
Zeeshan

Comment: This question is out of date. Google maps v3 allows free accounts to use SSL. See https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#ssl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a proxy in your webapp that will proxy the requests through to the Google Maps API. This will only work if you're not going to be performing more than 15,000 requests daily (I believe that's the limit). Google throttles by limiting the number of requests to 15,000 per IP.